# How do I cover all the edges of a graph with the minimum amount of nodes?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, np

I am stuck with a NP problem for a few days, and I´m looking at new ways to look at the problem.

The city has 360 security cameras that need to be placed in all of the street intersections of a city. The  idea is to look for the minimum amount of cameras that need to be placed in order to have all the streets covered .

[image]

The cameras can only cover one block unfortunately.

I am looking at each intersection as graph nodes while the streets are the edges, and initially I thought it was some kind of Chinese postman problem but that algorithm works mainly if you want to travel from one starting node and cover all the edges and return to the initial node.

So how would you cover all the streets with the minimum amount of cameras?

Any kind of enlightenment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how many blocks covers a camera?

Comment: The cameras can only cover one block unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Covering all edges in a graph by choosing a minimum number of vertices is the [(Minimum) Vertex Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover). It's an NP-**complete** problem, so the best known algorithms for solving general instances take exponential time. (Like all NP-complete problems, it's also in NP, but this is not a helpful description here as many simple problems are too.)

However, some subclasses of graphs can be solved much more quickly. Bipartite graphs is one such class, and a grid graph (or subgraph of such) is bipartite, so you're in luck. For grid graphs, the vertices with even coordinate sum (the black dots in your diagram) constitute one of the parts in the partition, and the vertices with odd coordinate sum constitute the other: notice that there are no edges between vertices within the same part. A minimum vertex cover can be found by first finding a maximum cardinality bipartite matching, for example in O(|E|*sqrt(|V|)) time using the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), and then applying [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)#Constructive_proof).

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is fast and simple to implement.  It gives a good, though not always optimal, answer.

1. Copy graph to working copy
2. Select arbitrary link connecting nodes u, v
3. Add u and v to cover set
4. Remove all links from u
5. Remove all links from v
6. Repeat until no links left in working copy
7. Remove from cover set any leaf nodes ( nodes with just one link )

The [PathFinder](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder) **cams** option is a C++ implementation of this algoritm using C++ and the boost graph library.

This input

```
l 0 1 1
l 0 2 1
l 1 2 1
l 2 3 1
l 2 4 1
l 2 5 1
```

gives

[image]

C++ code:

```
   // store indices of nodes that cover links
    std::set< int > setCover;

    // working copy on input graph
    auto work = myGraph;

    graph_traits<graph_t>::out_edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
    
    // loop until all links are covered
    while (num_edges(work))
    {
        // select first link in working graph
        auto it = edges(work).first;
        int u = source(*it, work);
        int v = target(*it, work);

        // add  non leaf nodes on selected link to cover
        if( out_degree( u, myGraph ) > 1 )
            setCover.insert( u );
        if( out_degree( v, myGraph ) > 1 )
            setCover.insert( v );

        // remove all links that can be seen from new cover nodes
        for (boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges(u, work); ei != ei_end; ++ei)
        {
            remove_edge(*ei, work);
        }
        for (boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges(v, work); ei != ei_end; ++ei)
        {
            remove_edge(*ei, work);
        }
    }
```